# Converting part of a byte[] to Enum

Tags: c#, .net

I am converting two properties `string TokenValue` and `TokenType` which is `enum TokenType : byte` I am able to convert to a byte array using the below method and separating the two properties with a %.

```
public byte[] ToByteArray()
{
    List<Byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    bytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TokenValue));
    bytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("%"));
    bytes.Add((byte)this.TokenType);
    return bytes.ToArray();
}
```

My problem is trying to convert back using:

```
    public void FromByteArray(byte[] value)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex("%");
        string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value);
        string[] fields = reg.Split(str);
        if (fields.Count() > 1)
        {
        TokenValue = fields[0];
        TokenType = (TokenType)Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fields[1]); //Something along these lines to convert back to the TokenType
        }
        else if (fields.Count() == 1)
        {
        TokenValue = fields[0];
        }
}
```

Not sure how to convert the bytes back to the `enum TokenType` 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you mix `Encoding.ASCII` and `Encoding.UTF8` like that? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ToByteArray()` you convert everything to bytes and then concatenate the byte values. Therefore, in `FromByteArray()`, you need to split the byte array *before* you decode it into strings etc:

```
public void FromByteArray(byte[] value)
{
    var delimiter = (byte)'%';

    var stringBytes = value.TakeWhile(b => b != delimiter).ToArray();

    var enumByte = 0;
    if (stringBytes.Length < value.Length)
    {
        enumByte = value.Last();
    }

    TokenValue = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stringBytes);
    TokenType = (TokenType)enumByte;
}
```